# How to correctly set the hostname for the TCP/IP adapter on the ESP32

Tags: c, tcp, embedded, driver, esp32

#### Problem

Espressif's ESP-32 (specifically the ESP-WROOM-32 in this case) appears on a network with the default hostname "Espressif". I don't want to use this hostname, so I've opted to change it as follows:

```
    // Initialize the TCP/IP adapter (launches handler task)
    tcpip_adapter_init();

    // Set the hostname for the default TCP/IP station interface
    if ((err = tcpip_adapter_set_hostname(TCPIP_ADAPTER_IF_STA, g_hostname))
            != ESP_OK) {
        return err;
    }
```

Of course, this isn't working. I get back the following error: `ESP_ERR_TCPIP_ADAPTER_IF_NOT_READY`.

---

#### Attempted Solutions

To solve this, I look to see if the TCP/IP adapter will post some kind of event when it is finished initializing. That way I can register a handler to set the hostname. The [Espressif WiFi Driver Guide](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/api-guides/wifi.html) here indicates a task is launched - so there is probably an event right:

> "The main task calls tcpip_adapter_init() to create an **LwIP core task** and initialize LwIP-related work."

Well I cannot find any such events. Neither the [API documentation](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/api-reference/network/tcpip_adapter.html) nor the actual file itself (`tcpip_adapter.h`) have it. I checked the header file for events, and **none seem to exist solely for the purpose of indicating that the TCP/IP adapter has finished starting**:

```
/** IP event declarations */
typedef enum {
    IP_EVENT_STA_GOT_IP,               /*!< ESP32 station got IP from connected AP */
    IP_EVENT_STA_LOST_IP,              /*!< ESP32 station lost IP and the IP is reset to 0 */
    IP_EVENT_AP_STAIPASSIGNED,         /*!< ESP32 soft-AP assign an IP to a connected station */
    IP_EVENT_GOT_IP6,                  /*!< ESP32 station or ap or ethernet interface v6IP addr is preferred */
    IP_EVENT_ETH_GOT_IP,               /*!< ESP32 ethernet got IP from connected AP */
} ip_event_t;
```

#### Possible Lead

I have noticed that in [Espressif's WiFi guide](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/release-v3.0/api-guides/wifi.html#system-event-sta-start) they indicate that the event `SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_START` (which indicates that a station has started), will:

> Upon receiving this event, the event task will initialize the LwIP network interface (netif).

If I place the call after a handler receives this event, I no longer get the error:

```
    // After the event WIFI_EVENT_STA_START
    if (base == WIFI_EVENT && id == WIFI_EVENT_STA_START) {

        // Set the hostname for the default TCP/IP station interface
        if ((err = tcpip_adapter_set_hostname(TCPIP_ADAPTER_IF_STA, g_hostname))
                != ESP_OK) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Err: %s", esp_err_to_name(err));
        }
        ...
    }
```

However, the hostname still hasn't changed. Therefore I find myself a bit stuck. How can I actually change the hostname? I've found little to no results from searching this problem. However, the esp32 is a popular module and I'm sure many other people will find themselves facing the same problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out I was doing it correctly. It was my router that had failed to refresh the hostname adequately. For consistency I will restate what I did to solve this problem:

---

The [Espressif WiFi Guide](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/release-v3.0/api-guides/wifi.html#system-event-sta-start) indicates that the event `SYSTEM_EVENT_STA_START` is generated once `esp_wifi_start()` returns successfully.

The generation of this event also means that the event task will initialize the LwIP network interface (netif). Since we know that the TCP/IP adapter will surely have been initialized at this point, we can invoke the hostname change function. Here is an example of a handler that does that, taken right from their example:

```
void wifi_event_handler (void *handler_arg, esp_event_base_t base, int32_t id,
    void *event_data) {
    esp_err_t err;

    // If esp_wifi_start() returned ESP_OK and WiFi mode is in station mode
    if (base == WIFI_EVENT && id == WIFI_EVENT_STA_START) {
        const char *name;

        // Set the hostname for the default TCP/IP station interface
        if ((err = tcpip_adapter_set_hostname(TCPIP_ADAPTER_IF_STA, g_hostname))
                != ESP_OK) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Err: %s", esp_err_to_name(err));
        } else {
            if ((err = tcpip_adapter_get_hostname(TCPIP_ADAPTER_IF_STA, &name)) != ESP_OK) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Err Get Hostname: %s\n", esp_err_to_name(err));
            } else {
                printf("Hostname: %s\n", (name == NULL ? "<None>" : name));
            }
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

In this example I get the hostname after setting it, and print it to `stdout`. You can validate it if you are running the monitor for the ESP32. The hostname set will be the one visible from the router page.

Comment: You also need to register the handler. The matching base and id is checked at this point. And therefore, I don't think you really need to check the event and id in the handler itself. 
`esp_event_handler_instance_register(WIFI_EVENT,WIFI_EVENT_STA_START, wifi_event_handler, NULL, NULL);`